# Delete method doesn't delete a node with specific name

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

Hi guys i am trying to delete a node that has a specific name. but apparently doesn't delete the node it just prints out everything. The node that contains the name doesn't get deleted. I wrote my linked list and everything works except deleting a node that has a specific name. Below is my method for deleting a specific name:

```
 public void remove(String name)
{
    if(!this.isEmpty())
    {
        LinkedList current = first;
        //LinkedList prev = null;
        while(current!=null)
        {
            //prev = current;
            if(current.name.equals(name))
            {
                current = current.getNext();
                count--;
                break;
            }
            current=current.getNext();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot search an empty list");
    }
}
```

main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Link a = new Link();
     a.addEnd("Tom"); //adds at the end of list
     a.addEnd("Joe");
     a.addEnd("Gary");
     a.add("Kim"); //adds at the beginning of the list
     a.addIndex("Nene", 1); //adds to an index position.
     a.remove("Kim"); //calls the method to remove the name kim but doesn't delete it.still displays kim on the console.
       a.display();
}
}
```

Comment: You need the previous node to delete current node. Or you can move all the data from the next node to the current one but this won't work if it's the last node in the linked list.

Comment: There's no line in your code that attempts to delete a node, that's the problem. You do `current = current.getNext()` when the name matches and when the name doesn't match. You should be changing at least one of the links in the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

I think a very minor adjustment will get this working.  I'm making the assumption that you're extending the built-in Java LinkedList:

In your conditional:

```
if(!this.isEmpty())
{
    LinkedList current = first;
    //LinkedList prev = null;
    while(current!=null)
    {
        //prev = current;
        if(current.name.equals(name))
        {
            // Right here you need to do a this.remove(current.getId)
            current = current.getNext();
            count--;
            break;
        }
        current=current.getNext();
    }
}
```

You're decrementing the count, but you're not actually removing the element from the list. Java's built in LinkedList has a remove by ID method: [LinkedList.remove](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(int)). Since you've got the element that matches the name, then you should be able to pass the index of that element's ID to the remove method.

If you're not doing this as an extension of the existing method then I would recommend using a look ahead. Know your current and your next. That way you can follow this logic (pardon my pseudocode):

```
If next matches, do next.getNext()
If next.getNext() returns null,
    then pop the last value off the list (current.setNext(null))
Else
    do current.setNext(next.getNext())
```